# How do you enable server-side encryption when streaming data using Apache Flume to Amazon S3

Tags: encryption, amazon-s3, flume

I am streaming some sensitive log data to Amazon S3 using flume. I can't figure out how to set the flag/configuration in flume so that S3 uses server-side encryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually experienced the same problem myself. Full details are [here](http://engineering.aweber.com/amazons-sorta-simple-storage-solution/).

You need to add the following property to your core-site.xml

```
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3n.server-side-encryption-algorithm</name>
    <value>AES256</value>
  </property>
```